# Security implications of allowing CORS for localhost

Tags: javascript, web-services, security, cors

I have a server, say at `api.myserver.com`

For testing, we often connect to it (make an xhr request) from `http://localhost`

Now, I can set up CORS on the server to allow requests from localhost, but my question is what real-world attacks (xss or otherwise) am I exposing to my users?

Thanks!

Comment: none, except for users that are running localhost and using your API from it. if you login or use keys, then none none. The only theoretical concern would be zombie attacks from an already compromised (XSS) page, but nobody runs localhost, and any language besides JS doesn't care about CORS.

Comment: fully agree with the comment above. CORS is only a security feature for web-cients (browsers) that respect the same-origin-policy.

Comment: So, to restate your answer: The risk would be if a user regularly used `http://localhost` for *something* and then would be potentially vulnerable to an XSS attack that CORS could have theoretically prevented

Comment: Yup, for it to cause a security problem the user has to run something on http://localhost, then he has to access http://localhost with his browser, and finally this page needs to have an XSS attack.